# Add ssh key string to .ssh/authorized_keys file

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I have a SSH key string, how would I add this to .ssh/authorized_keys file, does this need to be file already on the remote server?

Comment: when you say key string, you mean a, for example,  RSA key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do that for ssh to server without password. Yes the file (the key file) must be on the server side and added to the .ssh/authorized_keys .

You can do it in a single command:

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

This command append to ssh/authorized_keys your .ssh/id_rsa.pub.

More info: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: Great! Thanks, I have the key as a string, can i just save this as a .pub file from notepad?

Comment: Sorted it, just saved the pub file, ftp to server and ran the cmd line, thanks

Comment: Asuming you are using windows is just what @Josh said. If you use Linux you could solve it echoing the string in the before command. Start using Linux ;)

Comment: ```ssh: Could not resolve hostname b: Temporary failure in name resolution``` How can we do this with a manual string?

Answer (score 0):

The ssh-copy-id command (in the openssh-client package and installed by default) does exactly this:

```
ssh-copy-id -p PORT_NUMBER  USER@REMOTE_MACHINE
```

See more at https://askubuntu.com/a/4833/209229